# Standard solution for displaying names of chars c++?

Tags: c++, char

Is there a standard function for user-friendly representation of non-alphanum input characters?
Say char(27) would be "ESC" or "Escape" or something alike.
I am asking this because that would be an easy way for me to display help on controls in command line.

EDIT:

As @ypnos pointed out: **the question is how to avoid defining my own key names.**
I wonder if there was a function in boost or std or some basic lib which I missed?

For now, Ascii-only could work for me but I am looking for a "standard" solution because I don't want to reimplement once dealing with Unicode input -- say characters with accents not in Ascii -- later on.

My program code will be sent over to Linux and Windows and I also don't want that the names would be faulty at places.

Comment: I think the question is how to avoid defining your own key names.

Comment: Thx, also a possibility initializing `char char_names[255];` but I am looking for a better-looking solution.

Comment: Another, more old-school, variant is to have an array with 256 string entries, and use the character value as index into the array.

Comment: I am not aware of such a function. Also some of these names might be subject to localization, if that matters to you. Otherwise having a static string array that maps index to s symbolic name should be quiet easy to do - well, at least for char values < 127.

Comment: Names with respect to what character set and encoding? ASCII? Unicode?

Comment: Considering cross-cultural keyboard layouts and translated strings, this is likely to be platform-dependent. Which platform(s) are you targeting?

Comment: [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/) has got such facilities. A quick search gave me [this function](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/uchar_8h.html#aa488f2a373998c7decb0ecd3e3552079). A bit of overkill for ASCII only, but worth considering if you plan to support Unicode, IMO.

Comment: the closest you can get is GetKeyNameText, but it's Windows only. There  should be similar API in X.org for linux. I'm not aware of standard c/c++ or posix functions.

Comment: @jrok I took a look there. If you put your comment into an answer I'll vote it up.

Comment: Nothing in the standard even suggests that characters should have user-friendly names.

Comment: @aleguna I think it is also rather an answer.

Comment: @jrok: I suspect ICU's `u_charName` will just answer `<control>` for escape as that's what's written in the unicode master database. For key names, the platform-specific method has to be used. Each of Windows, Xlib, Qt, Gtk+, Cocoa etc. will have such method to use in keyboard shortcuts settings. Note that it's GUI frameworks, not operating systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most C++-y way would probably via a library such as [Ogonek](https://bitbucket.org/martinhofernandes/ogonek). Unfortunately, the relevant function isn’t yet implemented at the moment.

R. Martinho Fernandes (the maintainer) [tells me](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/6117141#6117141) that it should look as follows:

```
namespace ogonek {
    namespace ucd {
        …

        basic_text<utf8> get_name(codepoint u) {
            return basic_text<utf8> {
                find_property_group(name_data, name_data_size, u).name };
        }

        …
    }
}
```

And then you could simply display a Unicode code point’s (27, say) name using

```
std::cout << ogonek::ucd::get_name(27);
```

Comment: If that only uses the Unicode data file, it does not include names for control characters. All `UnicodeData.txt` installed on my system has to say about U+001B (27, Escape) is `<control>`.

Comment: Well, it can be obtained by querying for one of the aliases (namely, one of the "control" variety). That's not yet implemented either :(. The whole thing is still very alpha-y. Still, those are not key names, and in, names of keyboard keys, so I'm not sure if it helps.

Comment: A key on a keyboard is only indirectly related to a char anyway. There's no `'Ctrl'` char, for instance, or a `'F12'` char even though they're commonly found keys.